# Create new sprint under new release version in jira

Tags: jira, release, scrum, jira-agile, sprint

I'm having two release version as 1.5 and other new is release v2.0 in jira.
Till now I was having 16 sprints in Release 1.5 Now I want to have new sprints under release 2.0.

How can I do that? Is there something I'm missing or going in wrong direction?

Comment: The 16.0 Sprints are under release 1.5. Now I want to add new sprints under release 2.0. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprints are for ongoing agile development, where "releases" are related to more basic kanban workflows where you have a WIP (work in progress) workflow and just release active "sprints" into a release version.

When you use a Kanban software development project, it's not following the scrum agile project workflow model so it replaces the "sprint" with releases.  Once you fill your max WIP (say 10 tasks), once complete, you release the completed work into a release version.  This differs from a sprint because it's based off how much work your team is allowed.  Sprints, part of the scrum/agile project type in JIRA are run against date ranges.  Any uncompleted work in a sprint is moved to the next sprint.

If you're talking about these releases, what you can do is change the project type you're using and "versions" instead of releases.

Versions track independently of sprints and allow you to have a 1.5 and 2.0 version that can be tracked against multiple sprints.  Sorry for my previous answer.  Several products intermix version and release.

Comment: Chaseabbot, you stated that there's nothing like sprint under x release and y release. They are created as a common, nothing specialized to each release?
Sprint is a different entity.

Comment: Are you talking about kanban releases versus "versions"?  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I would suggest using versions in a scrum/agile project instead of releases in a kanban software dev.  This allows more flexibility for you and would get you what you want easily.  And the reports are quite easy to follow.

Comment: Chaseabbot... ur ans as of before was gud .. it's for scrum !!! ...

How swimlanes can be with Release?

Comment: Ahh... if you're using scrum then definitely, use versions and you can setup multiple versions simultaneously and drag/drop tasks between each one.  Once a sprint closes, all unfinished work would move to the next planned sprint.  We track multiple versions of our web site planning simultaneously (1.5 and 2.0) and we have both versions spread out between sprints.  And the backlog still has more.

Comment: that clear my much of thinking.. New to it!! and with admin accounts holds!!

Comment: And remember, Agile software development is supposed to be "agile".  So if you don't like one way to do things, changing how you do things in JIRA is totally ok!